# Adding district year fixed effects in a two year panel employing individual fixed effects

Tags: panel-data, dataset, fixed-effects-model, generalized-did

The data I have is longitudinal with two survey rounds. So I have a two-year panel. In the empirical set up I have employed individual fixed effects. Is it wrong to employ district-by-survey fixed effects as well in the model?
My research aims to find the labour market implications on a household member upon the death of another household member across two survey rounds. However I add the district survey fixed effects as well to control for any change in govt funding that might have acruied at the district level that might have hiked labor market particpation incentives. So control for the
any other time variant factor at the district level that might have propmted the indidvial to particpate in the labour market other than the death of an household member.

My concern is this, because its a two period model , the district-survey year dummy for the first year gets omitted. So practically there is only one other district-survey dummy thats being put to use. And since I already use survey FE and indidviual FE separately is the effect being already subsumed? IS it wrong to add district-survey dummies separatley along with individual and survey FE ina two period longitudinal panel.

```
egen district_id =group(STATEID DISTID)
egen distyear= group(district_id SURVEY)

* and then in the model I add the district survey FE like this
xtset INDid
xtreg y x i.SURVEY i.distyear , fe cl(IDPSU)
```